# Calling stored procedure in a function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to call a stored procedure in a user defined function in SQL Server.

I tried by calling the stored procedure inside a function using openrowset. But I'm unable to pass any parameter to that stored procedure. I want to pass this argument at run time to the function and the function should pass it to the stored procedure and then fetch values based on it.

Is this possible in SQL Server?

Comment: you cannot use the key word `EXEC` or `EXECUTE` inside a user-defined function in sql server.

Comment: http://www.dotnetfunda.com/forums/show/8955/how-can-call-stored-procedure-inside-function-in-sql-server-2005 I tried as given in this link, I'm able to call my procedure in a function but my problem is 'm unable to pass parameters in the exec given in this openrowset. Can that be fixed?

Comment: if you want to call a stored procedure within a function in my opinion you do not understand the concept of functions. Create a stored proc and from there you can exec other stored procs as needed